# Use of subclassing in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, numpy

I'm trying to write a finite-element simulation in object-oriented Python as a personal curiosity project.  This is one of the first fully OO projects I've done, so I'm still learning the details of OO implementation.

To start, I have a Mesh class that is essentially the following:

```
# Simulation mesh
class mesh:
    def __init__(self, nx, ny):
        self.nx = nx # Number of cells in x dimension
        self.ny = ny # Number of cells in y dimension
```

I also thought it would be prudent, in my case, to have separate classes for electric field and magnetic field (both of which have multiple methods and multiple numpy arrays), as well as UPML (same) and some other auxiliary objects, for computational purposes.  I reasoned that these should be subclasses of the mesh class and inherit the size of the mesh, so that when these objects are created, they are automatically the same size as the mesh natively.

I'm having difficulty inheriting the properties of the mesh class in this way though, so I'm wondering if anyone is able to explain how to correctly use super() in this case and how I can automatically inherit the parameters nx and ny from a mesh object to an electric field (among others) object once I instantiate it.

If there are better ways to structure this type of program, that would also be wonderful advice. Thanks.

Comment: You inherit from the *class*, not from the *instance*; you can inherit the attributes `nx` and `ny`, but if you want to have the same *values* inheritance isn't necessarily what you're looking for.

Comment: What technique would allow me to do that then, besides directly pulling the attributes from a mesh object when I create the other objects?

Comment: So will you have the values of `nx,ny` when calling the subclasses?

Comment: You could have a classmethod, e.g. `Mesh.match_size`, that takes a `Mesh` instance and returns a new instance with matching values of `nx` and `ny`. Then if you do subclass for other reasons (e.g. additional methods) the subclasses inherit that classmethod too: `field = ElectricField.match_size(mesh)`

Comment: I'm not sure that every single class has to have nx and ny fields- as long as the arrays contained within them are matched in size to the current mesh object, I don't see a need for the size to explicitly be included as a field.  Especially since this can be accomplished using numpy.size(fooclass.array1) for example.

Comment: @Scott OK, then use that.

Comment: If you're more curious about FEM than OO, you might want to checkout FENICS (http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/tutorial/index.html). I really like the way they implemented their python interface.